# React Native Expo SDK version is outdated

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, frontend, expo

I am trying to run via android an old React Native project(which made a year ago) and got this message in my phone on expo application: "Something went wrong. This project uses SDK v37.0.0, but this version of Expo Go requires at least v39.0.0.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: update the sdk version in `app.json` and also update the react native version in `package.json` file. Maybe some of the changes may required due to updating the version.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the guide to the indicated expo sdk. Generally, it is `expo upgrade`.

For SDK version 39, the guide to upgrade your project can be found in this link

https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-39-is-now-available-1lm8

Support for SDK v39 has already been dropped. So you must upgrade to at least v40.

You'll find a section on how to upgrade SDK version. Do keep in mind expo sdk v43 is currently in beta, so it is wise to upgrade to v42 as they will be dropping support for sdk 40 in the next update sometime in December.

You can find all SDKs here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/